# Repeat the re-sampling function for 1000 times ? Using lapply?

Tags: r, lm, statistics-bootstrap

Please me out! I appreciate any helps ! Thanks!

I have trouble on repeat doing re-sampling for 1000 times.
I tried using replicate() to do that but it's not working. Is there any other method to do that? Can anyone show me if this maybe done by using lapply?
 Following is my code:

```
#sampling 1000 betas0 & 1 (coefficients) from the data
get.beta=function(data,indices){ 
  data=data[indices,] #let boot to select sample
  lm.out=lm(y ~ x,data=data)
  return(lm.out$coefficients)
}
n=nrow(data)
get.beta(data,1:n)

bootcoe=boot(data,get.beta,R=1000) #generate 1000 random samples
head(bootcoe$t) #look at the betas
```

From the above code I can get 1000 betas0 & 1 by random sampling the data. And I would like to do that 1000 times to get different betas. How should I do that besides replicate()?

Comment: So `replicate(1000, {your_codez})` isn't working?

Comment: ya, I have tried rep(1000, function())but can't get the result.

Comment: I didn't say to use `function()`. You should use curly braces.

Comment: FYI, `replicate` is a wrapper for the common use of `sapply` for repeated evaluation of an expression. `sapply` is itself  a user-friendly version and wrapper of `lapply` that returns a vector or a matrix instead of a list.

Answer (score 29):

This is more of an extended comment where I demonstrate that `replicate` should work. Here's an example of a CLT. Just replace your lines what's between the curly braces.

```
x <- replicate(1000, {
  mm <- runif(10)
  mean(mm)
  })
hist(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Roman. So in my case, which should I put inside the {} ? I tried put get.beta but it gives errors, and having bootcoe runs for a long time. Putting both get.beta and bootcoe gives error again.

Comment: Also, why there is mean(mm) at the end? Thanks !

Comment: @user2978129 the last line is the result of your function. You should put between braces the things you want to be evaluated.... `n` times.